# gem Paperclip interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip, interpolation

Good day.
I have rails 3.1. and gem Paperclip
in my application to manage companies contracts:

```
MODEL    
    model/contract.rb
      has_many :contract_files

    model/contract_file.rb
      has_attached_file :data

CONSOLE
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.0)

1.9.2p290 :001 > cont = Contract.first

  Contract Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "contracts".* FROM "contracts" LIMIT 1    
         => #Contract id: 1, organization: "Com.org", and etc ....

1.9.2p290 :002 > cont.contract_files

  ContractFile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "contract_files".* FROM "contract_files"
     WHERE "contract_files"."contract_id" = 1     
         => #[ContractFile id: 88, caption: "asdf", and etc ...]
```

QUESTION
Be kind, tell me please, how can I extract **Contract id: 1**  in

```
model/contract_files.rb    
      has_attached_file :data,
      :url => "/assets/paperclip/:contract_id/:filename"
```

EXAMPLE WHAT I WANT TO GET
    On http//localhost:3000/contracts/1 get such files pathes:
    http//localhost:3000/contracts/1/assets/paperclip/1/XXX.pdf
    http//localhost:3000/contracts/1/assets/paperclip/1/XXY.pdf
    http//localhost:3000/contracts/1/assets/paperclip/1/XXZ.pdf

Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it clear you might do it this way:

```
Contract.find( params[:id] ).contract_files.map { |cf| cf.data.url }
# Dont't forget to handle nonexistent id
```

Upd

To place contract_id in url you should recover default paperclip :url and :path parameters this way:

```
#model/contract_file.rb
has_attached_file :data, :path => "public/contracts/:parent_id/assets/paperclip/:id.:extension", :url => "/contracts/:parent_id/assets/paperclip/:id.:extension"

Paperclip.interpolates :parent_id do |a, s|
    a.instance.contract.id
end
```

Comment: 1.9.2p290 :007 > cont.contract_files.map { |cf| cf.data.url} 
 => ["/assets/paperclip/data/88/original/download.jpg?1328369668"]                       but as you can see there's still no contract.id

Comment: Is there belongs_to :contract directive in ContractFile definition ?

Comment: https://github.com/itsNikolay/sophia  I pushed it, guess it will be more convenient for you. :)

Comment: Don't fork this :) Your solution works! I spend whole day on it. Great thanks for helping!

Comment: Damn, bundle install is in progress ))) Good luck )